# Set default length for node id

Tags: nodes

Is there a way to set the node ID length for a specific content type?

I want to have a specific content type have an ID of 8 digits long so that it can be used as a claim number for the clients paper work.

How would I go about setting this default?

Answer (score 3):

It's generally considered bad database design to give primary keys any business meaning. Just think what will happen if your business changes and your claim number format isn't the same anymore. Changing primary keys in DB is very hard to do.

Malks advice is very good. Add a specific claim ID field to your content type and use [token](http://drupal.org/project/token) and Automatic Node Titles module and maybe [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) to get nice URLs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that I know of to do that as the id is an autoincrement column in the base table. What you could do is use something like [Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) and hide the title field so that the title becomes your key.